# How to read MultiValue ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, multivalue

I've defined a arrayList as following

```js
    List<List<RiskyPersons>> dataArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here is RiskyPersons Class

```js
public class RiskyPersons {
    private SA3Tenant sa3tenant;
    private int NumberofPersonInCategory;
    
    public RiskyPersons(){
    }

    public RiskyPersons(SA3Tenant sa3tenant, int NumberofPersonInCategory) {
        this.sa3tenant = sa3tenant;
        this.NumberofPersonInCategory = NumberofPersonInCategory;
    }
}
```

Then I've successfully added data and saved in `dataArray` ArrayList.
Following output is showing the saved `ArrayList` using SOP(dataArray);

```html
[[RiskyPersons{sa3tenant=Homeless.SA3Tenant@3a7cc6b0, NumberofPersonInCategory=99}]]
```

**I want to read this `dataArray` ArrayList and display values separately. How do I access "NumberofPersonInCategory" value?**

Comment: When you have a 2D array list, you need to call get twice. `List<RiskyPersons> first = dataArray.get(0);` That gets you the first list. `RiskyPersons rp = first.get(0);` Now you have a risky person and you can use the attributes of that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to iterate it twice as

```
for (List<RiskyPersons> rp : dataArray) {
for (RiskyPersons o : rp) {
    System.out.println(o.NumberofPersonInCategory); // unrelated : but its bad naming convention
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From Java-8 and above one can use [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```
dataArray.stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .map(RiskyPersons::NumberofPersonInCategory)
    .forEach(System.out::println)
```

Comment: I mean should be there as good practice in class to call in Method reference

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you !

```
public class RiskyPersons {
    private SA3Tenant sa3tenant;
    private int NumberofPersonInCategory;

    public int getNumberofPersonInCategory() {
        return NumberofPersonInCategory;
    }

    public RiskyPersons(){
    }

    public RiskyPersons(SA3Tenant sa3tenant, int NumberofPersonInCategory) {
        this.sa3tenant = sa3tenant;
        this.NumberofPersonInCategory = NumberofPersonInCategory;
    }
}


List<Integer> values = dataArray.parallelStream().flatMap(Collection::stream).map(RiskyPersons::getNumberofPersonInCategory)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```